# Get ArrayList entry of a HashMap Entry

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Here is a (hopefully) simple question.
How can I get an entry in a ArrayList Object that is stored in a HashMap Object.
I know that you can write by:

```
stateIndex.put(nameOfEntry, arrayList);
```

But how can you access it?
EDIT:
To clear things up, I need to access an Element in the list.
I've tried

```
stateIndex.get(nameOfEntry).get(Arraylist Index);
```

But it doesnt work!

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the `ArrayList` or an element *inside* the list?

Comment: Why don't you read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and figure that out by yourself? You might even learn other things.

Comment: Could downvoters please tell me what I did wrong so I can write better answers in future?

Comment: What you did wrong: not reading the javadoc, which answers your question (-1 for lack of research). Saying that "it doesn't work" without any kind of explanation: what is the input, what is the output you expect, what is the output you actually get (-1 for unclear question).

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind on my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) method.

```
stateIndex.get(nameOfEntry);
```

You set with `put` and access with `get`.

If you want to get a specific element, just chain the `get` method for `ArrayList`.

```
Whatever element = stateIndex.get(nameOfEntry).get(5);// For any type.
```

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I need to be able to retrieve an element from the List